# Bootstrap Whole Image as a Button

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a sweet looking Button in Bootstrap. I have 4 images which show the discrete states of my button (Normal, Hover, Pressed, Disabled).

But I cant figure out what the best practice for this is. using the src in an input type image doesnt seem to be working that nice, since browsers will create a blue rect when clicking.

(I just need the whole image to be the button, its not a logo or smth that needs to be displayed on a certain position)

EDIT: its for my custom facebook/google/outlook login buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace the url's with the images you have.

```css
.fb {
  background: url(http://placehold.it/50x20/00ff00);
}

.fb:hover {
  background: url(http://placehold.it/50x20/0000ff);
}

.outlook:disabled {
  background: url(http://placehold.it/50x20/000000);
  color: white;
}

.fb:active {
  background: url(http://placehold.it/50x20/666666);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="fb">button</button>
<button type="button" class="outlook" disabled>button</button>
```

Comment: thank you this actually works, but only when setting the width to the exact width of the image, is there a workaround for this?

Comment: You can set a value for background-size. Experiment with 100%, cover and contain to see which one most fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice will be to use :before elements where You will be displaying image on "button".

Answer (score 0):

You can use img tag inside anchor tag to do so
For toggling between the states you can use jQuery.

Let me know if you require any further help!!